# There's no jar in dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I'm using Ehcache monitor with version ehcache-monitor-kit-1.0.3. When start the ehcache monitor server, an error occurs saying

```
 Exception in thread "CounterManagerImpl Timer" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.
sf.ehcache.Ehcache.getStatistics()Lnet/sf/ehcache/Statistics;
        at org.terracotta.ehcachedx.monitor.probe.SampledCacheStatistics$1.call(
SampledCacheStatistics.java:87)
        at org.terracotta.ehcachedx.monitor.probe.SampledCacheStatistics$1.call(
SampledCacheStatistics.java:85)
```

I found that method `getStatistics()` is different in interface of different version ehcache-core-xx.jar, if version < 2.7.0, that is what I need, but when add dependency in pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

,in the local repository, I found

```
 14 10:59 _maven.repositories
 14 10:59 ehcache-2.6.0.pom
 14 10:59 ehcache-2.6.0.pom.sha1
```

, so there's no line like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 Administrator 197121 6718989 Aug 14 10:58 ehcache-2.7.0.jar
```

no the jar, what should I do?

Comment: Try finding the dependency  using  $ mvn dependency:tree .

Answer (score 0):

you try to upgrade the version of `ehcache` to `2.10.4`. you can find the dependency below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
```